# LINQ XML- Read XML data

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am having trouble with LINQ query for XML and can't solve

I am trying to extract the  element values

Here is the XML

```
<response>
  <make>DODGE</make>
  <make>CHRYSLER</make>
  <make>JEEP</make>
  <make>RAM</make>
  .......etc
</response>
```

Here is the code I have so far...

```
        XElement parsedXml3 = XElement.Parse(xml3);
        var query2 = from m in parsedXml3.Descendants("response")
                     select m.Elements("make").Select(e => e.Value);
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        foreach (var o in query2)
        {
            ls = o.ToList();
        }
        ls.Sort();
```

Thanks for your help - extended explanations would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
XElement parsedXml3 = XElement.Parse(xml3); //parse your xml string
```

There is no need to use `parsedXml3.Descendants("response")` because response is root node here

```
var makes= parsedXml3.Elements("make") //Get All make Elements
           .Select(x=>x.Value).ToList(); //Select Value from make Element 
                                         //and Store in List<string>
makes.Sort();
foreach (var  make in makes)
{
   Console.WriteLine(make);
}
```

or you can modify your code to

```
XElement parsedXml3 = XElement.Parse(xml3);
var ls= (from m in parsedXml3.Descendants("make")
             select m.Value).ToList();

//List<string> ls = new List<string>();
//foreach (var o in query2)
//{
//    ls.Add(o);
//}
ls.Sort();
```

Comment: This is a great explanation! Thank you very much for your time. I was a bit confused on how to handle the "root node".